# Filtering python dictionary when values are lists

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

Let's say I have the following dictionary in Python

```
dict_results = {
    "first_names": ["john", "james", "carlos"],
    "last_names": ["smith", "jones", "sanchez"],
    "test_grade": [83, 79, 81]
}
```

I need to select the person with the lowest test_grade, which in this example is james jones. How do I get the following output:

```
filtered_dict = {
    "first_names": ["james"],
    "last_names": ["jones"],
    "test_grade": [79]
}
```

Comment: that's certainly a possibilty, let me try that

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of promoting Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_results)
df.loc[df['test_grade'].idxmin()].to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use the `min` function with a custom `key`, and a `for` loop to create a new dictionary.

```py
dict_results = {
    "first_names": ["john", "james", "carlos"],
    "last_names": ["smith", "jones", "sanchez"],
    "test_grade": [83, 79, 81]
}

# Find the index of the person with the lowest test_grade
lowest_grade_index = min(range(len(dict_results["test_grade"])), key=dict_results["test_grade"].__getitem__)

# Create a new filtered_dict dictionary
filtered_dict = {}

# Iterate over the keys in dict_results and add the filtered values to filtered_dict
for key, values in dict_results.items():
    filtered_dict[key] = [values[lowest_grade_index]]

print(filtered_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
lowest_grade = min(dict_results["test_grade"])

# List of multiple in case there is a tie of lowest score
indices = [
    i for i, score in enumerate(dict_results["test_grade"])
    if score == lowest_grade
]  

filtered_dict = {
    key: [val for i, val in enumerate(lst) if i in indices] 
    for key, lst in dict_results.items()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed your list a bit, you can work around with the idea I found and I used it for your example.

```
dict_results = {
    #"first_names": ["john", "james", "carlos"],
    #"last_names": ["smith", "jones", "sanchez"],
    #"test_grade": [83, 79, 81]
    'john smith': 83, 'james jones': 79, 'carlos sanchez': 81
}

x = list(dict_results.values())
d = dict()
x.sort(reverse=True)
x = x[-1:]
for i in x:
    for j in dict_results.keys():
        if (dict_results[j] == i):
            print(str(j) + ": " + str(dict_results[j]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```py
filtered_dict = {key: [values[lowest_grade_index]] for key, values in dict_results.items() if (lowest_grade_index := min(range(len(dict_results["test_grade"])), key=dict_results["test_grade"].__getitem__))}
```

Comment: This won't work if the lowest grade happens to be the first in the `test_grade` list. To demonstrate that, change the 83 in the provided input to 73.